# how to choose an id that has only one row?

Tags: mysql, sql

i have this table:

| id | item |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | a |
| 1 | b |
| 2 | c |
| 3 | d |
| 3 | g |
| 3 | f |
| 4 | ggg |
| 4 | gf |

i want that the query will show:
only 1 id (randomly from the options)
that has only 2 or less items
(that means- to show 1 id from the ids: 1,2 or 4)

Comment: Use `GROUP BY id` and `HAVING COUNT(*) <= 2`

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
select id
from test_tbl
group by id
having count(item) <=2
order by rand() limit 1;
```

> Rsult:
>
> ```
> id
> 2
> ```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e46b07188a57dd641e6232d6d6c6e9af)

[HAVING](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html)

[RAND()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_rand)